# Can I use my old Sony Handycam TRV815 as a web cam?

Tags: webcam, camcorder

Has anyone ever used their old Sony Handycam (or maybe any older hand-held camcorder) as a web cam?  As in streaming the live video from the cam to a web server (local or remote/Internet).

My TRV815 has a pretty darn good picture quality for its time..  Via USB or Ethernet.   It has S-Video but I think that is input.  It has RCA out (white/red for audio and yellow for video) and I have used that to display to my TV.

I have web cams already but was wondering if I could put this one to use also just for kicks..

Comment: try your question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I disagree - chances are the solution is either a simple matter of a suitable interface, and suitable software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i'm assuming like many cameras of the era, it supports firewire - you could use that interface and suitable software - this instructables post talks about [a few alternatives for the latter](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-Your-Camcorder-as-a-Webcam/) to turn it into a webcam. Unfortunately all the software mentioned is more expensive than a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your Sony camcorder  (I use TRV350) you must first download a free software called splitcam.

SplitCam.Softonic.com

The firewire for some reason will not upload audio to your PC for skype use. The video is fine. For the audio you must connect a mic to your mic input of your PC.